# How to use multi_match with indices in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have 2 indices **USER** and **URL**. I want to run a query on different fields based on the index.

In **USER** index, query should search in **name** and **id** field.
But in **URL** search has to be performed on **title** and **id** field.

```
POST /_search    
    {  
       "query":{  
          "indices":[  
             {  
                "indices":[  
                   "URL"
                ],
                "query":{  
                   "multi_match":{  
                      "query":"SMU ",
                      "fields":[  
                         "title",
                         "id"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             },
             {  
                "indices":[  
                   "USER"
                ],
                "query":{  
                   "multi_match":{  
                      "query":"SMU ",
                      "fields":[  
                         "name",
                         "id"
                      ]
                   }
                }
             }
          ]
       }
    }
```

The above query is not working. What is the change required to make it work.
How can I merge multi_match search with indices search?

Comment: Which ES version are you using? What doesn't work with the current query?

Comment: Currently, I'm using ES 5.1. The example query is not working. I looking for the query to do the job something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `indices` query is deprecated in ES 5, but it still works, you just have a bad structure in yours, i.e. you need to put each `indices` query in a `bool/filter` clause.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "indices": {
            "indices": [
              "URL"
            ],
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "SMU ",
                "fields": [
                  "title",
                  "id"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "indices": {
            "indices": [
              "USER"
            ],
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "SMU ",
                "fields": [
                  "name",
                  "id"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Since the `indices` query is deprecated, the new idea is to use a simple `term` query on the `_index` field instead. Try this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "URL"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "SMU ",
                  "fields": [
                    "title",
                    "id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": "USER"
                }
              },
              {
                "multi_match": {
                  "query": "SMU ",
                  "fields": [
                    "name",
                    "id"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much same what exactly I'm looking for. But in the above answer, it's trying to match both "URL" and "USER". How can I search in  "URL" or "USER".

Comment: I've replaced `filter` by `should` and you have it.

Comment: Absolutely perfect.